# Use Member functions of array which contains struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, member-functions

I made an array wit a struct for example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "utils/Configuration.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;    
struct plausibilitylinestruct{
        int x0;
        int y0;
        int x1;
        int y1;
        float p;
    } plausibilitylines[10];
```

How can I use member functions on the created array? [C++ Refernce for array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

I tried for example:

```
void addPlausibilitylines(vector<Vec4i> line) {
    if(plausibilitylines.empty()) {
        cout << "Test"<< endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added some more code

Comment: What you have is a raw C array. It does not have any member functions.

Comment: `plausibilitylines.empty()` is invalid, since `plausibilitylines` is not an object. The reference you linked to is of `std::array`, which you are not using here.

Comment: The reference you link to is for the *class template* `std::array`. What you're defining is a plain simple standard C-style array. Those two are different. I suggest you [find some good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply confuse *C*-style array and [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which was added since *C++11*.

*C*-style array obviously has no methods. In opposite, `std::array` is a container with its own set of methods.

To make use of `std::array` you have to convert your solution into something like:

```
std::array<plausibilitylinestruct, 10> plausibilitylines;
```

And then use methods like `empty()`:

```
plausibilitylines.empty();
```

Comment: An std::array is empty if and only if it was constructed with size 0. I don't think that that's what the OP wants to archieve